# Can I have a listitem in a dropdownlist with a value of 0 and an empty string for text?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I need a listitem in my asp.net dropdownlist that has a value of 0 and an empty string for text.  I am appending the results of a db query to it in my code.  If I have the following markup it renders as 0 for both the value and the text:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="dd1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
   <asp:ListItem Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Is there a way to have it how I want without creating a inserting a listitem object in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text=""></asp:ListItem>`?

Comment: @Chis Carew, you should put that as an answer so I can vote you up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `Text` property, e.g.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="dd1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
   <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Its times like this where i hate the vs ide intellisense.  It did not give me that as an option in the html editor.  It works!